# Select last ten items from a specific row in a table

Tags: sql, t-sql, ssms

I think this should be a pretty simple question to people who have some experience with database queries

I have a table

```
Line_ID Run_Date    Product_ID  Pallet_Cd   Run_Qty
1   2012-10-31 01:00:00.000 175 00801004718000000002    0
1   2012-11-28 12:38:01.340 6   00801004718000000003    72
1   2012-11-28 13:32:25.250 4   00801004718000000004    180
1   2012-11-28 17:03:30.937 8   00801004718000000005    72
1   2012-11-29 07:29:58.603 1   00801004718000000006    120
1   2012-11-29 08:03:10.597 6   00801004718000000007    72
1   2012-11-29 08:24:11.370 4   00801004718000000008    180
1   2012-11-30 11:21:56.253 6   00801004718000000009    72
```

please excuse the formatting but hopefully you can see what the table is supposed to be.

I want to get the next rows after a specific pallet_cd.

For example if i give the parameter a

```
pallet_Cd = "00801004718000000007"
```

I just want to bring back the rows for

```
pallet cd = "00801004718000000007, 00801004718000000008, 00801004718000000009"
```

Any help with this is appreciated!

Comment: 7, 8, and 9 because those are the next three rows ordered on pallet code, or because those are the next three rows ordered by run date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems pretty straightforward...

```
SELECT TOP 10 Line_ID, Run_Date, Product_ID, Pallet_Cd, Run_Qty
FROM YourTable
WHERE Pallet_Cd >= '00801004718000000007'
ORDER BY Pallet_Cd
```

This will select the next 10 records including the specified pallet code when you order by the Pallet_Cd.

Comment: Thanks, i was missing the order by!

Answer (score 1):

If the `pallet_Cd` are chronological just `ORDER BY Pallet_Cd` and to `SELECT TOP 10` `WHERE Pallet_Cd >= X`